# mysql how to extract data from multiple and sum

Tags: mysql

Quite new to mysql and have trouble formulating this type of query.

Under one table(table called tableX), let’s say structure is like below

```
server       date           numberofUser
 server1   timestamp        3
 server2   timestamp        2
 server3   timestamp        7
 server1   timestamp        2
 server2   timestamp        8
 server3   timestamp        4
```

….. and so forth

I know I can just do simple
         select sum(numberofUser) from tableX where server like ‘server1’ order by timestamp desc limit 100;
to get total of users for server1 for last 100 timestamp

But how would you do this for all 3 servers? I want to aggregate results for all 3 servers for 100 timestamp for each of the servers.. just quite not sure how to do this. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

Comment: You cant run sql across servers :(, you have to use some programatic intermediary

Comment: I will check out that post..  And yes, this is only from one sql server(under one table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use group by

```
select sum(numberofUser) , server
from tableX 
group by server
```

and limit your time period

```
select sum(numberofUser) , server
from tableX 
where timestamp between 'your_date_min' AND 'your_date_max'
group by server
```

The total for all the servers is  simply

```
select sum(numberofUser) 
from tableX
```

for the last 10 row of server1 and server2

the totale for single server

```
select sum(numberofUser), server from (
  (select  server,   date, numberofUser from tableX 
  where server = 'server1'
  order by date limit 10 )
  union 
  (select  server,  date, numberofUser from tableX 
  where server = 'server2'
  order by date limit 10 )) as t
group by server
```

or total  for the 2 server

```
select sum(numberofUser) from (
    (select  server,   date, numberofUser from tableX 
    where server = 'server1'
    order by date limit 10)
    union
   ( select  server,   date, numberofUser from tableX 
    where server = 'server2'
    order by date limit 10 )) as t
```

Comment: how would you add them up? instead of by server, how would sum up the total from all server?

Comment: Anyway i have update the answer  .. hope is this what you are looking for  .. and that may answer is useful for you.

Comment: so say, I wanted to I want to get total for server 1 and server 2 together for last 10 samples of each server.. that's what I wanted to run.. so something like..     select sum(numberofUser) where server like 'server1' or 'server2' order by desc 10

Comment: so my question is, if I did below, is this truly taking 10 samples from each server or 10 samples for whatever it matches     select sum(numberofUser) from tableX where server like 'server1' or 'server2' order by timestamp limit 10;

Comment: another words, based on timestamp, take last 10 samples from each server(say server1 and server2) and sum it

Comment: getting "Incorrect usage of UNION and order by" but I think you are on the path that I want to go

Comment: Solved  ...5 minutes for the solution

Comment: thank you so much.. I assume I can also do   order by date desc limit 10 right? I have accepted your answer btw, much appreciate it!!

Comment: actually, one more question, how would you output for each date? so.. if I want to output for each of the timestamp for total (server1+2)? Meaning, as long as there is unique timestamp(which there should be 10 of them), I want to total by timestamp.(well, 10 for each server but then add them according to right timestamp)